# Process scheduling confusion

Tags: scheduling

I've got a confusion in the following section of a book. Here we taking about FCFS Scheduling. I feel that calculation table is incorrect in the book. Because P3 got completed at time 7, it's turnaround time should be 7-3 because third process arrival time is 3 so why they take 1? Remember turn around time = t(process completed)-t(process submitted)

For P4 it's 11-4 which I feel wrong again. Further for P5. So I want to know whether I'm wrong in understanding this all or the following is really a wrong calculation. Can someone please explain. Thanks!
Check the fallowing links for book scan:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGtva.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVP03.jpg

Comment: However I gave a quick look at the tables and it seems that you are right: for P3, P4, P5 the table wrongly reports (completion time - processing time) instead of (completion time - arrival time). And as a consequence the waiting times on the rightmost column are also wrong.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi thanks ! I will remember your suggestion in further posts !

Answer (score 1):

Converting Vor's comment into an answer:

the table looks incorrect.

Specifically: for P3, P4, P5 the table wrongly reports (completion time - processing time) instead of (completion time - arrival time).